# Arduino Patterns Array Crashing

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, arduino

I am using an Arduino Uno to control two LEDs. The goal is to be able to create flash patterns easily (in an array) and have them cycled through and played.

I currently am using this array to store the patterns:

```
int patterns[][64][3] = {
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 500}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 500},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 250}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 250},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 125}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 250}, 
    {LOW, LOW, 250},
    {HIGH, LOW, 250}, 
    {LOW, LOW, 250},

    {LOW, HIGH, 250}, 
    {LOW, LOW, 250},
    {LOW, HIGH, 250}, 
    {LOW, LOW, 250},
  },
//  {
//    {HIGH, LOW, 125}, 
//    {LOW, LOW, 125},
//    {HIGH, LOW, 125}, 
//    {LOW, LOW, 125},
//    
//    {LOW, HIGH, 125}, 
//    {LOW, LOW, 125},
//    {LOW, HIGH, 125}, 
//    {LOW, LOW, 125},
//  },
};
```

The last pattern is commented out because when I add it, the Arduino doesn't run well. The output that would normally look like this:

```
Using data from EEPROM
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 0
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 1
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 0
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 1
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 0
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 1
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 0
CurrentPattern: 0, PatternPosition: 1
```

now looks like this:

```
00
00
00
00
00

00
00
01
```

I'm thinking that it could be some sort of memory issue.. but it seems that even if I use a patterns array like this one:

```
int patterns[][64][3] = {
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 500}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 500},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 250}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 250},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 125}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 125}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
  },
  {
    {HIGH, LOW, 125}, 
    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
  },
};
```

I get the same issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first array (with the last pattern commented out) uses `4 * 64 * 3 * sizeof(int)` bytes. Assuming that you have one of the 16-bit boards, that's `1536` bytes. If you uncomment the last pattern, then the array uses `5*64*3*2 = 1920` bytes. The other array (near the end of the question) also uses `1920` bytes. So if memory is the problem, then both arrays will have the same problem.

If you want to reduce the memory usage, then you'll need an alternative way to store the patterns.  One solution is to create an array of 2D arrays, where each 2D array is only as big as necessary.  For example, here are the five patterns declared as 2D arrays.  Note that the memory usage is only `(3+3+3+9+9) * 3 * 2 = 162` bytes.

```
int pattern0[][3] =
{
    {HIGH, LOW, 500},
    {LOW, HIGH, 500},
    {0,      0,   0}
};

int pattern1[][3] =
{
    {HIGH, LOW, 250},
    {LOW, HIGH, 250},
    {0,      0,   0}
};

int pattern2[][3] =
{
    {HIGH, LOW, 125},
    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
    {0,      0,   0}
};

int pattern3[][3] =
{
    {HIGH, LOW, 250},
    {LOW, LOW, 250},
    {HIGH, LOW, 250},
    {LOW, LOW, 250},

    {LOW, HIGH, 250},
    {LOW, LOW, 250},
    {LOW, HIGH, 250},
    {LOW, LOW, 250},

    {0,     0,   0}
};

int pattern4[][3] =
{
    {HIGH, LOW, 125},
    {LOW, LOW, 125},
    {HIGH, LOW, 125},
    {LOW, LOW, 125},

    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
    {LOW, LOW, 125},
    {LOW, HIGH, 125},
    {LOW, LOW, 125},

    {0,     0,   0}
};
```

Since the 2D arrays are not all the same size, you need a way to identify the end of each array. This can be done with a *[sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)*. In the examples above, I've used a value of 0 in the third column as the sentinel.

Assuming that the arduino compiler is smart enough to understand arrays of pointers to arrays, you can group all of the 2D arrays into a single array as shown below. The resulting array can be used just like the 3D array that you already have.

```
int (*patterns[])[3] =
{
    pattern0,
    pattern1,
    pattern2,
    pattern3,
    pattern4,
    NULL
};
```

Here's some test code that will prove/disprove that the array is setup properly, by printing out the patterns on the serial port.

```
void loop()
{
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; patterns[i] != NULL; i++ )
    {
        Serial.print( "Pattern " );
        Serial.println( i + 1 );
        for ( j = 0; patterns[i][j][2] != 0; j++ )
        {
            if ( patterns[i][j][0] == HIGH )
                Serial.print( "HIGH " );
            else
                Serial.print( "LOW  " );

            if ( patterns[i][j][1] == HIGH )
                Serial.print( "HIGH " );
            else
                Serial.print( "LOW  " );

            Serial.println( patterns[i][j][2] );
        }
        Serial.println( "" );
        delay( 500 );
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I was trying to do something like this by finding some sort of array list or mutable array equivalent..I totally forgot about pointers.